# How do I make Text appear on an image when mouse pointer hovers over

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to make an clickable image. But it should be like when I hover over image it should get blurred with some color and new text should appear on it.
I am starting to learn CSS. It's interesting than HTML :D Thanks.

Comment: You must always add code when you are asking a question : [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
I have anyway posted a generic answer for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

To access the CSS you would use

> img:hover { }

But if you plan on creating text over the image you will need to use a script such as Javascript to make that happen.
Check out the link below for css

jsfiddle.net/HAcE2/

Comment: Okay! Can I please get some more info about JS code? I am a complete beginner.

Comment: Alright forget about JS, there are ways you can do it will CSS it just requires more time and effort to get the positioning right. Check the link in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Example(HTML/CSS):

```css
ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}


span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="img-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAADcEU/owwzfBaECbQ/s0-c-k-no-ns/photo.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
      <span class="text-content"><span>Google</span></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To add animation you may use :

```
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
```

Add this with in the `span.text-content`.